# How to do aggregate functions, may columns and extract back

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In spark-sql-2.4.1v , I have a scenario where I need to calculate few aggregate given columns list i.e. interested columns

**Each column I need generate few aggregations on the same grouping by columns.
Is there any way to perform group by once for all , and get those aggreations back?**

If I do each item ( i.e. interest columns) at a time then I need to group by the data multiple times , it is taking huge time.

Let say I have

```
   columns_interestedList.stream().forEach( col_interested  -> {
         Dataset groupByResDs_col_interested  = dataDs.groupBy("grp_col_1","grp_col_1").agg(count((*).as("col_interested_count") , avg(col_interested  ).as(col_interested_avg)));
    }

    );
```

As show above i need to get all interested columns aggregations at a time , how to do it ( to avoid group by for each col_interested  )

***Once I do all columns, how to get back them like below :***

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
col_interested_one      col_interested_one_count      col_interested_one_avg
col_interested_two      col_interested_two_count      col_interested_two_avg
col_interested_three    col_interested_three_count    col_interested_three_avg
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to make all the `groupBy` with the same columns, and you want to create all the aggregation column references as `avg(col_interested  ).as(col_interested_avg)` with all the elements of `columns_interestedList` you can create all the references with the stream, and pass them to the gag method.

```
List<Column> avgCols = columns_interestedList.stream()
.map(col_interested -> avg(col_interested).as(col_interested + "_avg"))
.collect(Collectors.toList());

dataDs.groupBy("grp_col_1","grp_col_1")
.agg(avgCols.add(count((*).as("col_interested_count").toArray(new Column[0]));
```

Comment: You want each average in a row, with the name of the column that got that average. The counts will return always the same values. Also, in your example you don't have the values of the columns which you make the aggregation, is that correct?

Comment: Put a better example of the input, output and the list of columns